# Javascript error stack tracer difference android ios

Tags: javascript, typescript, webview, ionic3, sentry

I'm currently adding [sentry](https://sentry.io) solution to help me debugging my Ionic3 application.

I used this [guide](https://gonehybrid.com/how-to-log-errors-in-your-ionic-2-app-with-sentry/) to set up sentry in my app. But there is something I don't really understand. For a same error, iOS stacktrace and Android one are different. So it become a mess really fast...

Eg: I add `throw new Error('foo')`at some point in my app to see what's happening. (I've not upload sourcemap for this test in order to have a raw stack)

The result is :

Android :

```
 Error: foo
  at OffersPage.webpackJsonp.54.OffersPage.sortPopover(/main.js:6789:15)
  at handleEvent(/vendor.js:13607:172)
  at callWithDebugContext(/vendor.js:15092:42)
  at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent](/vendor.js:14679:12)
  at dispatchEvent(/vendor.js:10056:25)
  at ? (/vendor.js:10670:38)
  at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>(/vendor.js:39220:53)
  at HTMLButtonElement.wrapped(/vendor.js:127102:21)
  at t.invokeTask(/polyfills.js:3:15660)
  at Object.onInvokeTask(/vendor.js:4970:33)
  at t.invokeTask(/polyfills.js:3:15581)
  at r.runTask(/polyfills.js:3:10834)
  at e.invokeTask [as invoke](/polyfills.js:3:16794)
  at p(/polyfills.js:2:27648)
  at HTMLButtonElement.v(/polyfills.js:2:27893)
```

iOS:

```
Error: foo
  at sortPopover(/main.js:6789:24)
  at callWithDebugContext(/vendor.js:15092:47)
  at dispatchEvent(/vendor.js:10056:36)
  at ? (/vendor.js:39220:65)
  at wrapped(/vendor.js:127102:26)
  at onInvokeTask(/vendor.js:4970:43)
  at runTask(/polyfills.js:3:10844)
  at invokeTask(/polyfills.js:3:16801)
  at p(/polyfills.js:2:27654)
  at v(/polyfills.js:2:27894)
```

As you can see, the iOS stack seems to be one on every two lines of the Android one. (If looking closer, lines numbers are the same, but columns differ a little bit).

Is this "normal" ? I can't find if it's due to the webview or if it's a ionic issue.

Doesn't someone already encounter this "problem" ?

Thanks,

Comment: Hey, we have a new Cordova SDK now which improves the experience.
We would love to get feedback on this https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cordova
It also works with Ionic see /docs

Comment: Thanks you for presenting me this, good news ! But docs link in repo are deadlinks and can't see cordova browsing docs from your website. Can I found it somewhere ?

Comment: This should do it
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cordova/blob/master/docs/ionic.rst

Comment: thx, will try it.